# How to use CreateAlloca to declare a vector in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to create a vector <8 *i8> in IR Pass. But I failed. I don't know what's wrong with my code. The code always crashed after I use 'CreateAlloca'

```
Type * new_vec = VectorType::get(IntegerType::get(Builder.getContext(),8), 8);
      errs() << "11111" << ":\n";
      AllocaInst *widen_vector = Builder.CreateAlloca(new_vec);
      errs() << "22222" << ":\n";
```

Comment: Try build LLVM in Debug/ReleaseWithAssert Mode and you will be able to see the assert message

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the parameter `ArraySize` of `Builder.CreateAlloca` to a `ConstantInt(8)`. If you don't give the value, the default is  `nullptr`, finally it will be set to `int32(1)` automatically. The source  code in Instructions.cpp is
`if (!Amt) Amt = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), 1);`
`Amt` is the `ArraySize`. Then there is a contradiction between the type and the size.